# Python and C++ integration. Python prints string as multiple lines

Tags: python, string, whitespace, popen, stdio

I'm trying to write a program in python to run a program in C++.  It wasn't working right, so I made the most basic version of each I could.
The C++ program merely takes in a string from stdin, and then prints it out.
The Python code is written as follows:

```
import popen2, string, StringIO

fin, fout = popen2.popen2("PyTest")
msg = ur"Hello, world!"
print msg
fout.write(msg)
print fin.readline()
```

The output, however looks like this:

```
Hello, world!
Hello,
```

The problem I keep seeing is that spaces seem to break apart the string, even though it is a string literal.  I'm not really sure what to do here.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Why aren't you using `subprocess.Popen`?

Comment: Is the C++ program flushing stdout?

Comment: When you call the C++ program by itself, does it return the desired output? I.e., `./PyTest Hello, world!` returns `Hello, world!`?

Comment: To elaborate on S Lott's comment: popen2: "Deprecated since version 2.6: This module is obsolete. Use the subprocess  module. Check especially the Replacing Older Functions with the subprocess Module section." http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess-replacements

Comment: It's a long story, but basically I'm just working with python 2.4.

And no, I just realized my C++ code doesn't do what I expected.  I forgot that cin handles spaces as multiple string inputs.  So it was only taking in one at a time.
HUBRIS WAS MY DOWNFALL!

Comment: You should post the above as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, `std::cin >> mystring` uses spaces as separators.  Use `std::getline` instead if you want to gobble up a whole line at a time.